# Can't run GWT application: org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.setReuseAddress(Z)V

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty

I am getting following exception, when I try to run my GWT application from eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.setReuseAddress(Z)V
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.setupConnector(JettyLauncher.java:529)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:662)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

At the same time the GWT Development Mode Tool opens, but nothing happens anymore.

[image]

I'm using maven for my project's dependencies and I already moved all entries to the bottom at the build class path settings. Still no change..

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You are using the wrong version of Jetty.

Comment: my maven repository says it's Jetty 6.0.2
How do I figure out, which version ist the "right" one for my purpose?